# Sphere Bounding Volume Collision OpenGL

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I am trying to make a pool table simulation where the balls will collide with each other after checking their radius and distance from each balls centre, against each other.

I have most of it set up and working, however I am very confused how to check every ball against each other at the same time. I currently have two for loops that sets two balls for each frame and checks their distance is less than the sum of their two radius. So it will only randomly hit some balls and make them collide.

Can anyone help me make all the balls collide when they should instead of randomly?

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#pragma once
// Math constants
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>  
#include <random>
#include<iterator>

// Std. Includes
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

// GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/matrix_operation.hpp>
#include "glm/ext.hpp"

// Other Libs
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

// project includes
#include "Application.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Body.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Force.h"
#include "RigidBody.h"
#include "Sphere.h"


// time
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;

// main function
int main()
{
// create application
Application app = Application::Application();
app.initRender();
Application::camera.setCameraPosition(glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f));

// create ground plane
Mesh plane = Mesh::Mesh(Mesh::QUAD);
// scale it up x5
plane.scale(glm::vec3(40.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f));
Shader lambert = Shader("C:/Users/Euan/Desktop/project2/resources/shaders/physics.vert", 
"C:/Users/Euan/Desktop/project2/resources/shaders/physics.frag");
plane.setShader(lambert);

//Create Sphere
Mesh sphere = Mesh::Mesh("resources/models/sphere.obj");

//Gravity
Gravity g = Gravity(glm::vec3(0.0f, -9.8f, 0.0f));

//Spheres vector
std::vector<Sphere>spheres;

//Amount of balls
int balls = 100;

//Create 100 balls and set them with random velocities in x and y
for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++)
{
    Sphere s;
    int pos_z = (rand() % 80) - 40;
    int pos_x = (rand() % 80) - 40;
    int vel_z = (rand() % 20) - 10;
    int vel_x = (rand() % 20) - 10;
    s.setMesh(sphere);
    s.getMesh().setShader(Shader("resources/physics.vert", "resources/physics.frag"));
    s.translate(glm::vec3(pos_x, 0.5f, pos_z));
    s.scale(glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    //s.rotate((GLfloat)M_PI_2, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    s.setVel(glm::vec3(vel_x, 0.0f, vel_z));
    s.setCor(1.0f);
    s.addForce(&g);
    spheres.push_back(s);
}

//Table walls
glm::vec3 table(40.0f, 0.5f, 40.0f);

// time
GLfloat t = 0.0;
GLfloat dt = 1.0f / 60.0f;
GLfloat currentTime = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
GLfloat accumulator = 0.0;

float m = 1.0f;

// Game loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(app.getWindow()))
{
    // Set frame time
    GLfloat newTime = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
    GLfloat frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
    currentTime = newTime;
    accumulator += frameTime;


    /*
    **  INTERACTION
    */
    // Manage interaction
    app.doMovement(dt);

    while (accumulator >= dt)
    {

        /*
        **  SIMULATION
        */

        //Loop through all balls and send them in their directions
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++)
        {
            spheres[i].setAcc(spheres[i].applyForces(spheres[i].getPos(), spheres[i].getVel(), t, 
dt));
            spheres[i].setAngVel(spheres[i].getAngVel() + dt * spheres[i].getAngAcc());
            glm::mat3 angVelSkew = glm::matrixCross3(spheres[i].getAngVel());
            glm::mat3 R = glm::mat3(spheres[i].getRotate());
            R += dt * angVelSkew * R;
            R = glm::orthonormalize(R);
            spheres[i].setRotate(glm::mat4(R));
            spheres[i].setVel(spheres[i].getVel() + spheres[i].getAcc() * dt);
            spheres[i].translate(dt * spheres[i].getVel());


            //Keep ball above table
            if (spheres[i].getPos().y < table.y)
            {
                spheres[i].setPos(1, table.y);
                spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor(), 
spheres[i].getVel().y * -spheres[i].getCor(), spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor()));
            }
            if (spheres[i].getPos().y > table.y)
            {
                spheres[i].setPos(1, table.y);
            }

            //Colliding with x sides of table
            if (spheres[i].getPos().x > table.x - .5f)
            {

                spheres[i].setPos(0, table.x - .5f);
                spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, 
spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor() / 
1.5f));
            }
            if (spheres[i].getPos().x < -table.x + .5f)
            {
                spheres[i].setPos(0, -table.x + .5f);
                spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, 
spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor() / 
1.5f));

            }

            //Colliding with y sides of table
            if (spheres[i].getPos().z < -table.z + .5f)
            {
                spheres[i].setPos(2, -table.z + .5f);
                spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3((spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, 
spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * -spheres[i].getCor() / 
1.5f)));
            }
            if (spheres[i].getPos().z > table.z - .5f)
            {
                spheres[i].setPos(2, table.z - .5f);
                spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3((spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, 
spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * -spheres[i].getCor() / 
1.5f)));
            }

            //Reduce speed of balls over time
            float x = spheres[i].getVel().x;
            float y = spheres[i].getVel().y;
            float z = spheres[i].getVel().z;
            glm::vec3 vec = glm::vec3(x / 1.005f, y, z / 1.005f);
            spheres[i].setVel(vec);

        }


        //Check for collisions with radius of two balls
        for (size_t i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < spheres.size(); j++)
            {
                float d = glm::distance(spheres[i].getPos(), spheres[j].getPos());
        
                float radiusI = spheres[i].getScale()[0][0];
                float radiusJ = spheres[j].getScale()[0][0];
        
                if (d <= radiusI + radiusJ)
                {
                    spheres[i].setVel(-spheres[j].getVel());
                    spheres[j].setVel(-spheres[i].getVel());
                }
            }
        }           

        accumulator -= dt;
        t += dt;

    }

    /*
    **  RENDER
    */
    // clear buffer
    app.clear();

    // draw groud plane
    app.draw(plane);

    for each (Sphere s in spheres)
    {
        app.draw(s.getMesh());
    }

    app.display();
}

app.terminate();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My main issue is with this part:

```
//Check for collisions with radius of two balls
    for (size_t i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < spheres.size(); j++)
        {
            float d = glm::distance(spheres[i].getPos(), spheres[j].getPos());

            float radiusI = spheres[i].getScale()[0][0];
            float radiusJ = spheres[j].getScale()[0][0];

            if (d <= radiusI + radiusJ)
            {
                spheres[i].setVel(-spheres[j].getVel());
                spheres[j].setVel(-spheres[i].getVel());
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I have all the balls colliding at once instead of checking any two balls very fast?

Comment: Look into 'continuous collision detection'.

Comment: Why does it only randomly check some balls? Your loop checks every ball with every other ball

Comment: sometimes the balls will just go right through each other. Especially if they have touched a wall it seems

Comment: also sometimes when colliding. One ball continues on the same direction whereas the other collides off in the opposite direction